# Inserting array into array

Tags: arrays, swift

So I wanted to insert the objects of an array into another array. Swift arrays seem to missing an equivalent method to `- (void)insertObjects:(NSArray *)objects atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes`, but all is well because we can use the following syntax:

```
var array = [0,4,5]
array[1..<1] = [1,2,3] // array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

All is well? Not quite! The following gives a compile-time error ("[Int] is not convertible to Int"):

```
var array = [0,4,5]
var array2 = [1,2,3]
array[1..<1] = array2
```

Is there a sane explanation for this?

Edit:

Ok, the following works (thanks Greg):

```
array[1..<1] = array2[0..<array2.count]
```

As well as this:

```
let slice = array2[0..<array2.count]
array[1..<1] = slice
```

But right now I'm utterly confused how this works. Gregs explanation that I was trying to insert `array2` itself into `array` makes sense, but I fail to see the difference to just using an array literal, as well as why it works with a slice (which seems to be an undocumented implementation detail?).

Comment: Slice conforms to  the ArrayLiteralConvertible protocol, that's why `array[1..<1] = [1,2,3]` works. But there is no automatic conversion from Array to Slice or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you want to insert an array2 (Array) not elements from the array,
try this:

```
array[1..<1] = array2[0..<array2.count]
```

Answer (score 3):

Range subscription on `Array<T>` works only with `Slice<T>`.

```
subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<T>
```

In your case, `array2` is not a `Slice<Int>`. That's why you see the error.

Usually, you should use `replaceRange()` or `splice()`, which works with arbitrary `CollectionType`.

```
array.replaceRange(1..<1, with: array2)
// OR
array.splice(array2, atIndex: 1)
```

---

Moreover, assigning to range on `Array` has some bugs I think. for example:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
array[1...5] = array[1...1]
```

The result array should be `[0, 1]` but it actually remains to be `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`. It only happens if the `startIndex` of the range is the same, and the slice is constructed from the same array.

On the other hand, `replaceRange()` works as expeceted:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
array.replaceRange(1...5, with: array[1...1])
// -> [0,1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for showing me the correct method to use.